# A few questions about design apps that I need cleared

Tags: civil-engineering

1. Can Revit be used for structural design like Prota Structure and STAAD Pro
2. Do design apps cancel the need for you to take a pen and paper to calculate the structural needs of a building. If so why learn somethings in class.

Answer (score 2):

yes revit can be used in structural design (provided you know how to use it).

Regarding the second part of your question (I will try to answer as politely as I can), revit --and software like it-- are just a tool that helps mainly with the tedious calculations and sometimes has some of the building codes incorporated.  However **a tool is not accountable, if a design is proven wrong in practice**, a person is.

And in my experience, even the most sophisticated software -- at least up to today-- cannot make a decision without the correct input (garbage in, garbage out). And, the problem is that usually most errors are detected in the post-processing (garbage out). So if you don't have the training (or the experience) to detect it you are going to either make a very expensive building (which is the good scenario), or some people will be injured or even killed (the worst case scenario). In both cases you will soon be out of business.